# Rails: Rendering Partials through Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a page with tabs and I want to just render different partials through ajax when the tabs are clicked upon. I have some code but I don't think it is the most efficient way. I was hoping if anyone can help me with my code that is already in place or if there is an easier method I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

**HTML Tab**

```
<li class='StreamTab StreamTabRecent active'>
<%= link_to 'Most Recent', mostrecent_schools_path, :remote => true, :class => 'TabText' %>
</li>


<div id='ContentBody'>
<div id='ajax'></div>
<%= render 'users/microposts', :microposts => @microposts %>
</div>
```

**School Controller**

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController  
  def mostrecent
    @school = School.find_by_slug(request.url.gsub('http://localhost:3000/','')).id
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
  end
end
```

**Most Recent JS**

```
$("#ContentBody").html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "users/microposts" )%>');
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :schools do
    collection do
        get :mostrecent
    end
  end
```

Comment: "I have some code but I don't think it is the most efficient way". Is the above code working properly? Do you want to optimize this process or you want a working code in the first place ?

Comment: @prasvin That code isn't working, was trying to make it work from something I found on the internet before but I am not sure how to get it going or if it is the most efficient way. If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears to learn :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See my answer to a previous post. This will give you an idea [AJAX in Rails: Show model#new form after completing a model#update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154874/ajax-in-rails-show-modelnew-form-after-completing-a-modelupdate/9156082#9156082)

What you can do is render a json in the action and pass the partial as json.

```
def mostrecent
  @school = School.find_by_slug(request.url.gsub('http://localhost:3000/','')).id
  @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {:success => true, :html => (render_to_string 'users/microposts')} }
    format.html { }
  end
end
```

You can access the json in your js (i.e. a javascript/coffeescript file such as mostrecent.js or mostrecent.js.coffee) and replace the current element.

```
$('.TabText').live 'ajax:success', (event,data) ->
  $('#ContentBody').html(data.html) if(data.success == true)
```

Comment: I appreciate this very much :)

Comment: Do write back if the above does not work, or you are not sure about something. The code is untested but should pretty much get you close to achieving your task.

Comment: I never used json before but I image instead of a js file I create a json file and add that into it?

Comment: No, you need not create the js views ( I guess that is what you are referring to by js file, say foo.js.erb). That is the whole point of rendering json. All you need to do is capture the rendered json in your javascript/coffeescript file, and you are done (my answer says "You can access the json in your js", i.e. your javascript file say mostrecent.js) . No js views. I suggest you go through http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/ since that is what I read about 8 months ago.

Comment: I have a mostrecent.js file but it is under the school file and also is it alright just deleting everything inside of that file and just add your json code into it?

Comment: I guess the logic behind avoiding js views is first and foremost they are hard to debug, since you have your javascript scattered in a lot of places. Its better having them at one location, say your javascripts folder in app/assets. Secondly,(and this is more important), it avoids sending client side information from the server. I mean, why send divs, span, links from the server. Do that by your js. The only thing the server should be concerned with is sending the required data(or objects/values). However, bear in mind, that my solution does not comply to the second logic.

Comment: Ideally, we should be rendering `@microposts` via json and building the view in our js according to the logic. But, that avoids the use of partials that rails provides us. So, I guess above solution is more easy and realistic. Generally, if I need to render a whole page or a partial, I pass the entire thing as json. But, if I need to add a small element after ajax completes, & that thing is not yet in the view, I simply render `@whatever` via json and manually put the divs and stuffs by js. Since, creating a new page for that might lead to a lot of pages(which essentially is same as js views).

Comment: Yea, go ahead and delete the content if you do not require it. And put the json code in your javascript file, say mostrecent.js

Answer (score 2):

Prasvin's answer is spot-on. Returning and executing JS may seem simple but it makes debugging much nastier - how do you set a breakpoint in JS that was returned via AJAX? Instead you should include all of your JS in the page and only send data back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rails 4.2 and @prasvin answer pointed me in the right direction but when I used

```
format.json { render :json => {:success => true, :html => (render_to_string 'instruments')} }
```

I would get an error "Missing template ... instruments..."

After some reading i found this comment [rails render_to_string giving errors with partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078439/rails-render-to-string-giving-errors-with-partial-view). @marcel mentioned you need to specify the file is a partial, partial: 'instruments',  as below:

```
format.json { render :json => {:success => true, :html => (render_to_string partial: 'instruments')} }
```