# How can I change the .erb rendered in a <div> with a button click in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, render, erb

I am a newbie to RoR, and I was using Chartkick with HighCharts to display some graphs from my sqlite database. The graphs are daily and weekly, so I have two .erb-s with the query for each of them, and I want the index.html.erb dynamically change between them in my  with a click of a button.

This is the code from the daily_graph.erb:

```
<div><%= line_graph Product.where(date_time: "2014-03-03 00:00:00".."2014-03-03 23:45:00").group(:date_time).sum(:value) %></div>
```

This is the code from the weekly_graph.erb:

```
<div><%= line_graph Product.where(date_time: "2014-03-03 00:00:00".."2014-03-09 23:45:00").group(:date_time).sum(:value) %></div>
```

How can I manipulate with these views in my index.erb, so when I click the WEEK button, daily_graph will disappear, showing weekly_graph, and the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) Keep the views dumb. Do the SQL query inside the controller, and set it as a variable that the view accesses. So, it would be:

```
# Inside your controller

def index
  @daily_products = Product.where(date_time: "2014-03-03 00:00:00".."2014-03-03 23:45:00").group(:date_time).sum(:value)
  @weekly_products = Product.where(date_time: "2014-03-03 00:00:00".."2014-03-09 23:45:00").group(:date_time).sum(:value)
end
```

Then your view would just be:

```
<div class="graph"><%= line_graph @weekly_products %></div>
<div class="graph hidden"><%= line_graph @daily_products %></div>
```

2) the `.erb` file is used for server-side templating, so switching back and forth would need to happen on the client side. You can have both graphs on the page and use an event handler to disable / show the respective graphs when the button is pushed.

On the index page, lets say you have `<button id="flipGraphs">Change</button>`

Using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(function(){ // If you are not familiar with jQuery, this will run when the page is loaded and ready
  $('#flipGraphs').click(function(){
    $('.graph').toggle(); // toggles all of the divs as hidden / shown
  });
});
```

Also, add this to your application.css file:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me more insights on how to create an event handler for disabling/showing the respective graphs please? It is the part where I need more help.

Comment: @uklp I added more to my answer to help you.

Comment: where should I add the jQuery code, inside the index.erb or into the application.js file?

Comment: Inside index.erb. Make sure to put it in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: The code you added seems logic, but both graphs are still being displayed when I load the page, and the button doesnt seem to affect anything. What can it be?

Comment: Can you add the code from your template? It is hard to tell what is going on without it.

Comment: `<button id="flipGraphs">Change</button>`

`<div class="graph"><%= line_chart @weekly_graph %></div>`
`<div class="graph" style="dislay:none;"><%= line_chart @daily_graph %></div>`

`<script>
    $(function(){ // If you are not familiar with jQuery, this will run when the page is loaded and ready
        $('#flipGraphs').click(function(){
            $('.graph').toggle(); // toggles all of the divs as hidden / shown
        };
    });
</script>`

Comment: Could you understand anything from this code? The formatting is not that clear.

Comment: Yep I missed ` )` in my code. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it works, it needs some CSS work because the second graph is shown smaller in size, but the main thing is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to turn those ERB `views` into `partials`... then you can make a new controller action that renders the particular partial your interested in, and you can fetch that controller action with jQuery ajax calls... see: [Rails: Rendering Partials through Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527925/rails-rendering-partials-through-ajax?rq=1) for more examples

Also conventionally you would not execute model finder methods in the `view` ... set controller instance variables and reference them instead... this will lead directly to an overall more DRY result.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had them turned into partials in one moment, and I will try that approach again. Though i still dont know clearly how to fetch the actions with jQuery ajax, but I will give a look at the examples now.