# Rails 4 and rendering partials with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building a static, single page app. I have a small number of partials that I'd like to render into a specific part of the page depending on the link that's been clicked.

**My HTML looks like this:**

```
<div class="feature" id="grr" data-title="some title" data-partial="grr">
</div>

<div class="feature" id="yum" data-title="some title" data-partial="yum">
</div>

<div class="stage">

 <nav>
   <h2 id="stage-title"></h2>
    <div id="close">
      <%=image_tag "close.png" %>
    </div>
 </nav>

 <div class="content">Content will go here</div>

</div>
```

**Coffeescript looks like this**

```
  # Open slide up menu
  $('.feature').click ->
    title   = $(this).data('title')
    partial = $(this).data("partial")
    $('#stage-title').empty().append(title)
    popout()
```

**In views/partials, I have things like**

- partials/_grr.html.erb
- partials/_yum.html.erb

Currently, I don't have any method for actually rendering the partial into the view. I've looked at a dozen different methods for doing this, but they all seem deeply complex compared to what I'm doing here. I seem to remember just using `$.get` for this sort of thing in Rails long ago, but that's not working. I'm also pretty rusty at Ajax in general. Hoping this makes sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that this app has a single controller, called static_pages_controller.rb. A lot of solutions I've seen involve adding actions in the controller, but that doesn't make a lot of sense for this (I don't think). I have just one action, an index, and I'd like to keep it that way for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I believe you are going to find what you need here: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2015/12/a-small-trick-to-use-ajax-with-rails.html

Comment: have you tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527925/rails-rendering-partials-through-ajax?rq=1

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to apply the answers in that thread to my situation. This seems like such a simple case, and most of that seems pretty in-the-weeds. Am I wrong?